# Change UIlabel text size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, xcode7

My text from the UIlabel isn't fitting in the screen, and I need it to be smaller. Just the text size. How do I change its size programmatically or using the Xcode ui?

Comment: Look for "autoshrink" in Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it fit automatically

[image]

Comment: The preferred size was what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Minimum Font Scale or size in Storyboard/Xib when you set it up in IB under the Attributes inspector.

I prefer scale, as it is better at fitting longer text on iPhone 4/5/iPod touches. If you set the size, you can get cut off earlier than with scale.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select **Minimum Font Size** in **Autoshrink** and give the minimum size you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]
```

or

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:8]
```

i.e.

```
[[self titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]];
```

Swift

```
var titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",size: 20.0)
```